# will useEffect callback clean up run if user closes tab or goes to a different website?

Tags: reactjs, use-effect

```
useEffect(() => {

  return () => clean_up();

}, [])
```

Will `clean_up` be runned if use closes tab or switches to a different website?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, and this is not particular to React. Once a document or window is closed (which includes being redirected to another page), no further JavaScript can execute in that window.

`setTimeout` will not run after the page is closed or redirected either, and neither will any other APIs provided by any other libraries, if they run on the client-side.